# NextJs load multiple files with loadFilesSync or glob,

Tags: graphql, next.js, glob, file-import

I am trying to load multiple files with `@graphql-tools/load-files` I have tried with `glob`, too, but no success there as well. My folder structure is like this:

```
/
/.next
/pages
/pages/api
/pages/api/graphql -> there I have an ApolloServer
/server
/types
/types/userTypes.ts
/types/authTypes.ts
```

And my idea is to have all graphql types in root/types folder as different files and merge them when build:
Here is a part of `graphql.ts` file.

```
import path from 'path';
import { mergeTypeDefs } from '@graphql-tools/merge';
import { loadFilesSync } from '@graphql-tools/load-files';

const typesArray = loadFilesSync(path.join(__dirname, '../../types/.*'));
console.log(typesArray);
```

the output is empty [] array. When I try this without NextJs is working as expected, so I guess NextJs is doing something with the folder structure, but I can't figure it out. If some one can help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right about how Next JS handles its folder structure

Replace `path.join(__dirname, '../../types/.*')` with `path.join(process.cwd(), 'path')` as seen here [with-typescript-graphql](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/74e0c6d6d85919479fffb1f83c4d98f679045158/examples/with-typescript-graphql/lib/schema.ts#L8)

Answer (score 0):

To follow on from the accepted answer-

Passing a hardcoded path did not work for me.

Instead , just use a glob pattern.

```js
loadFilesSync('**/*.gql')
```

The linked example uses `graphql-let` config which is essentially resolving to a glob pattern similar to this.